# HTML5 localStorage sets to "NaN"(jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I'm having a textfield there the users is meant to insert a URL then this code below should run and store the URL in "email" but instead of storing the URL it stores "NAN"...

```
    if ($("input[name='email']").val().length == 0 ){
    alert("You Need To Set A Email URL");
}
else{
    localStorage.setItem("email", +("input[name='email']").val);
}
```

Why? And what's wrong with the my jQuery?

Comment: `+` when used as a unary operator is a shortcut for `parseInt(_, 10)`

Comment: "Why? And what's wrong with the my jQuery?" Just ask your console. Often console like speaking.

Comment: @Kolink it's more a number parser, it parse a string to number (float/integer) not just to integer as parseInt()

Comment: Ah, yeah. So more like `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this

```
localStorage.setItem("email", +("input[name='email']").val);
```

Here are couple of problems

- You are retrieving input value properly. `val` is nothing in this case.
- `+` operator should not used in this case.

So try this

```
else{
     localStorage.setItem("email", $("input[name='email']").val());
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GMLEQ/)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

```
+("input[name='email']").val
^-- Should be $
--------------------------^ .val()
```

`.val()` is a method, you need to call it.
`$` is the correct alias for `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

try with parentesis

```
if ($("input[name='email']").val().length == 0 ){
    alert("You Need To Set A Email URL");
}
else{
    localStorage.setItem("email", +("input[name='email']").val());
}
```

Comment: Ops, i can't reply, when i typing there is already an answer :( sorry